# Will an upgrade install all main ubuntu desktop package?

Tags: upgrade, release-management

I installed Ubuntu and removed some default Ubuntu packages such as unity and scroll overlay. Will this packages be installed again if I upgrade to the next release of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the more common areas where an upgrade fails is when the `ubuntu-desktop` meta package has been removed when uninstalling various packages.

Most often you get the error `unable to calculate`.

You should always reinstall the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage before the upgrade. This will reinstall all `ubuntu-desktop` dependencies described in the [packages wiki](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/ubuntu-desktop)

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

You will have to remove any packages afterwards then was reinstalled but you no longer want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have to look now for the method of upgrading Ubuntu without the need to ubuntu-desktop package.

Comment: I have know found the solution of upgrading Ubuntu without ubuntu-desktop package. Here is the link http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1605468.html